# Zxing Barcode Reader How detect a barcode which is in the top side of page

Tags: java, barcode, zxing

We are trying to read a barcode using zxing lib. The barcode is in the top right of page but its place can change apprx. 40 px to right left or up down. How can I detect its certain place.

Comment: ZXing can only see the image that it gets. The whole point of using such a third party system is to abstract over ideas like the position of the barcode.

Comment: Yes, ZXing great works when I specify exact place of barcode. Do you know a lib which finds position of the barcode.

Comment: maskapsiz , I am having the exactly same problem. Did you find out how to do that?

Comment: We are cutting the area according to status of finding. For example if it is not finding in the first try, we increase the size of cutting area. Sometimes we are scanning whole page.